# Iodoform reaction of alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I read from a source that 2-iodopropane undergoes iodoform reaction. What reaction mechanism is undergone here, and why does this happen?

Comment: Mention the source.

Comment: Well, it was an online test for JEE Adv Prep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Aaron.

It will.

Because Iodide is very good leaving group. In iodoform test, we use base... which will convert 2-iodopropane into propan-2-ol. The latter will give haloform the same way as ethyl alcohol and any other methyl ketone does!
[image]

Comment: Oxidation of isopropanol to acetone using halide? This isn't a common reaction

Comment: Okay. How then would ethanol be giving haloform reaction...
This is oxidation by halogen [NOT BY HALIDE]. Halogens are good oxidizing agents!

Comment: Are you able to give a mechanism for the reaction? Or a source in the original literature oxidising isopropanol with just a halide/halogen?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloform_reaction

Go to mechanism section
Reaction sequence 2

Comment: In that case, will any CH3CHX- group give the iodoform reaction? (X = halogen)

Comment: Yes!

Except that of CH3CH*F*-R